# xmodmap is not working properly on resume

Tags: 11.10, startup, xmodmap, resume

Since upgrading to 11.10, `xmodmap` seems to be working nowhere near as well.  I would like to be able to run `xmodmap` after unlocking a locked screen, as it doesn't work.  I have to run it from a terminal (twice).  I don't want Caps_Lock or Menu keys after I log in.

Preferably, I would like `xmodmap` to go back to being useable.  It doesn't run automatically at startup anymore like it used to.  I have a script at startup that has to run it several times before it actually does things.  Here is my `.xmodmaprc` file; hopefully somebody will be able to find something wrong:
`clear mod1`
`clear mod3`
`clear mod4`
`clear lock`
`keycode 66 = Hyper_L`
`remove lock = Hyper_L`
`add mod3 = Hyper_L`
`keycode 133 = Alt_L`
`add mod1 = Alt_L`
`keycode 64 = Super_L`
`add mod4 = Super_L`
`keycode 135 = Super_R`
`add mod4 = Super_R`
`keycode 118 = Multi_key`

Meanwhile, if fixing this file doesn't fix the problems I'm having, I would like to know how to run `xmodmap` after resuming from suspend or unlocking from a locked screen.

Answer (score 2):

I am also having this problem on 11.04. This was not always the case -- it just started happening to me some day, so my best guess is that it was due to some sort of software update.

Nevertheless, it is extremely irritating. I found [this thread](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/289781), which suggests that you can add a script `/etc/acpi/resume.d/50-xmodmap.sh` that runs on wakeup to invoke `xmodmap`.

Though someone else suggested that this bug may not get fixed and that you may be forced to use the GUI. Because my desired remapping is pretty simple (I just want to remap Caps Lock to Control), that's what I did. This was actually tricky to find, as I had to:

- Find the Keyboard GUI app
- Choose the Layouts tab
- Click the Options button
- Expand the "Ctrl key position" header because the desired option was not under "Caps Lock key behavior"
- Check the "Make Caps Lock an additional Ctrl" box

Admittedly, if you're a long-time `.Xmodmap` user, this is pretty annoying, but it's better than running `xmodmap` manually every time you log in.

Comment: Can I get an example of such a script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name of your xmodmap file to ~/.Xmodmap

That's the name of the file which Ubuntu looks for which gets processed by xmodmap each time you start an X session.

Comment: Could you supply some kind of source reference for that statement? It has no effect in my particular case...

Answer (score 0):

It seems xmodmap support is being phased out:

> xmodmap support has been dropped in GNOME3 which deprecate that bug report, closing it

(from [Bug #289781 on xserver-xorg-input-evdev](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-evdev/+bug/289781))

The graphical configuration **Tweak tool** might offer the settings you need. You can install it with `apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` and use the tab *Typing* to configure some common keyboard tweaks. (The same settings used to be in the standard System Settings [before Ubuntu 12.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1245064)).